# Calculate weighted average from objects with Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a simple `Measurement` class:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Measurement {
    private BigDecimal rawValue;
    private BigDecimal weighting;
}
```

The service processes a `List<Measurement>` and shall calculate a weighted average by applying the following steps:

1. Multiply each `rawValue` with its `weighting`.
2. Build the sum of all weighted raw values from (1).
3. Divide the sum (2) by the sum of all weightings.

**Example**

`(1.0 * 5.0) + (2.0 * 2.0) + (3.0 * 7.0) / 14`

Here is my current implementation:

```java
public class MeasurementService {

    private List<Measurement> measurements = new ArrayList<>();

    public MeasurementService() {
        Measurement m1 = new Measurement(new BigDecimal("1.0"), new BigDecimal("5.0"));
        Measurement m2 = new Measurement(new BigDecimal("2.0"), new BigDecimal("2.0"));
        Measurement m3 = new Measurement(new BigDecimal("3.0"), new BigDecimal("7.0"));
        measurements.add(m1);
        measurements.add(m2);
        measurements.add(m3);
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateWeightedAverage() {
        final BigDecimal totalWeighting = measurements.stream()
                .map(measurement -> measurement.getWeighting())
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
        return measurements.stream()
                .map(measurement -> measurement.getRawValue().multiply(measurement.getWeighting()))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                .divide(totalWeighting, 3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    }
}
```

While this is working, I don't like using the stream of `measurements` twice and I bet there is a better way. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with one so far.

Do you have any idea how to simplify the `calculateWeightedAverage` method?

I'm using Java 17.

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code  is better asked at [CodeReview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 12 or higher, to avoid to have to stream over the list twice, you can use the [teeing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) collector. In addition to the docs here is an article about it [the-teeing-collector](https://dzone.com/articles/java-12-the-teeing-collector)

```
public BigDecimal calculateWeightedAverage() {
    return measurements.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, m -> m.getRawValue().multiply(m.getWeighting()), BigDecimal::add),
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Measurement::getWeighting, BigDecimal::add ),
                        (weightedRawValues , totalWeighting) -> weightedRawValues.divide(totalWeighting, 3, RoundingMode.DOWN)));
}
```

Comment: Uuuh, teeing is a good choice! I also like the `Collectors.reducing` overload which you have picked. Very concise!

Answer (score 1):

Map to a new class and reduce that, then use the reduced value to compute the final result. This will work for Java 8+. Something like:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ResultAccumulator {
    public static final ResultAccumulator ZERO = new ResultAccumulator(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO);

    private final BigDecimal weightedValue;
    private final BigDecimal weightSum;

    public static ResultAccumulator fromMeasurement(final Measurement measurement) {
        return new ResultAccumulator(
                measurement.getRawValue().multiply(measurement.getWeighting()),
                measurement.getWeighting());
    }

    public ResultAccumulator merge(final ResultAccumulator other) {
        return new ResultAccumulator(
                getWeightedValue().add(other.getWeightedValue()),
                getWeightSum().add(other.getWeightSum()));
    }

    public BigDecimal getFinalResult() {
        return getWeightedValue().divide(getWeightSum(), 3, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    }
}

public BigDecimal calculateWeightedAverage() {
    final ResultAccumulator result = measurements.stream()
            .map(ResultAccumulator::fromMeasurement)
            .reduce(
                    ResultAccumulator.ZERO,
                    ResultAccumulator::merge);
    return result.getFinalResult();
}
```

Or do it quick and dirty and reduce your original `Measurement` by storing the "weighted value" in `rawValue` and the sum of weights in `weight`. The structure of both classes is the same, but using two classes is less confusing to others and yourself in 2 weeks.